# How to convert convert docx to jpg soffice

Tags: php, libreoffice

How to convert all pages of a docx file to jpg? How to convert a specific page to jpg, the first page from my docx as an example.

Command: `soffice  --convert-to jpg --outdir c:/tmp/ c:/tmp/loc1.docx`

Comment: The output_filter_options are underdocumented. Try the `unoconv` frontend instead, with e.g. `-e PageRange=2`

Comment: Thnks! Really it is not underdocumented.